# Responsive HTML Design issue with Margin and cannot pinpoint

Tags: html, css

Forgive the dumb question as I am sure its related to a margin I cannot seem to figure out how. Currently working on responsive html design for a basic website. The code works just find for two of the 3 @media sources I set but for some reason the in between size media runs into a visual issue.

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vhxs5jeb/

I believe this may be related to a `margin-right: 10px` but I don't see why.

[image]

The issue only appears when the display is in between 762-991px. I am simply overlooking something but don't see the reason. The endpoint for the second section is not meeting the end of the page as the 3rd section. Like I said super simple but I can't seem to see it myself. Otherwise the site works as intended.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code necessary to reproduce the issue. A link out to a jsfiddle isn't sufficient, because links go dead over time.

Comment: I gave the entire code to you in the fiddle if you looked.

Comment: Please read my comment again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the misalignment is `width: calc(50% - 10px)`

The sections have a 10px right margin. When the viewport is between 762-991px, the margin of the second section is reduced to 0 and the width of the first two sections is calculated to be 50% - 10px, but there's only 10px of margin between the two sections. Therefore, the width of the top row is 10px less than the third section.

Divide the 10px margin between the two sections and use that for the calculation.

```
@media (min-width: 762px) and (max-width: 991px){
  section{
    width: calc(50% - 5px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I figured it had to do with the margin-right I set in the section element but I could not figure out for the life of me where this margin was messing it up. Your suggestion corrected this.